# Наслоение фрагментов и не работающая кнопка вверх у toolbar

Tags: java, android, android-fragment

Пытаюсь сделать приложение singleActivity(Учусь). Пытаюсь сделать по схеме
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

На данный момент застрял на том, что фрагмент открывается методом replace по верх другого xthtp FragmentTransaction. При этом он именно наслаивается, и фрагмент по верх которого он наслоился активен("Лайфхак" с укажи фон у фрагмента который наслоился, помогает только визуально перекрыть фрагмент, но не устраняет, то что первый фрагмент еще активен и по нему можно кликнуть и открыть другой элемент списка) Пытаюсь так же сделать toolBar в Activity, что бы из фрагмента с детальной информацией об элементе recycleView можно было вернуться в recycleview кнопкой назад. По этому разместил его в именно activity, что бы в случае с большим экраном(Планшет) можно было разместить два фрагмента на одном экране.
Проект залит на git ветка navigation. Может кто сталкивался с таким и может чем помочь.

P.S.Ссылку на гит убрал в итоге. Google и подобные статьи здесь конкретно мне не помогли, возможно я что то на@!ев@#тил, что то.
Так же, если есть другой более правильный способ выполнить данную задачу, то буду благодарен за посвящение. Ибо только начал разбираться с данной темой и пока что очень плохо в ней ориентируюсь. Так же любой code review Приветствуется) Просто встречал только те примеры где реализуется только часть подобных задач или используют 2-3 activyty в одном собственно список а в другом детализация.

Код ActivityMain

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private Film film;
    private Toolbar toolbar;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolBar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);


    }
    public void replaceFragment(final Fragment fragment, Film film){

        if(fragment!= null){
            if (fragment instanceof FilmDetailFragment){
                toolbar.setTitle(R.string.app_name);
                FilmsFragment f1 = new FilmsFragment();
                Log.d("MyTag", "if");
                FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.filmsContainer, f1);
                fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(null);
                fragmentTransaction.commit();
            }else if(fragment instanceof FilmsFragment){
                Log.d("MyTag", "else if");
                toolbar.setTitle(film.getLocalizedName());
                getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
                getSupportActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
                toolbar.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View view) {
                        onBackPressed();
                        Log.d("MyTag", "setOnClickListener");
                    }
                });
                FilmDetailFragment f1 = FilmDetailFragment.newInstance(film);

                FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.filmsContainer, f1);
                fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(null);
                fragmentTransaction.commit();
            }
            else {
                toolbar.setTitle("another");
                Log.d("MyTag", "another");
            }
        }else {
            toolbar.setTitle("null");
            Log.d("MyTag", "null");
        }
        this.film = film;

    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        super.onBackPressed();
        Log.d("MyTag", "Click home toolbar");
    }
 }
```

XML Activity

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <include 
        layout="@layout/tool_bar"
        android:id="@+id/toolBar"></include>

    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/toolBar"
        android:id="@+id/filmsContainer">

        <fragment
            android:name="com.example.films.fragments.FilmsFragment"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            tools:layout="@layout/films_fragment" />

    </FrameLayout>
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Код фрагмента списка

```
public class FilmsFragment extends Fragment {
    private RecyclerView recyclerView;
    private FilmAdapter filmAdapter;
    private GridLayoutManager gridLayoutManager;
    private List<Film> films;

    public FilmsFragment() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        films = new ArrayList<>();
        View view = inflater.inflate(
            R.layout.films_fragment, container, false);
        recyclerView = (RecyclerView) view.findViewById(R.id.filmsRecycler) ;
        if (recyclerView.getParent() != null){
            ((ViewGroup)recyclerView.getParent()).removeView(recyclerView);
        }
        gridLayoutManager = new GridLayoutManager(getActivity(), 2);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(gridLayoutManager);

        filmAdapter = new FilmAdapter(films, getContext());
        recyclerView.setAdapter(filmAdapter);

        RetrofitClient.getInstance().getApi().getFilms().enqueue(new Callback<Films>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<Films> call, Response<Films> response) {
                if (response.body() != null) {
                    films.addAll(response.body().getFilms());
                    recyclerView.getAdapter().notifyDataSetChanged();
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<Films> call, Throwable t) {
                Toast toast = Toast.makeText(getContext(), R.string.toast_text, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
                toast.show();
            }
        });

        filmAdapter.setListener(new FilmAdapter.Listener() {
            public void onClick(int position) {
            
((MainActivity)getActivity()).replaceFragment(FilmsFragment.this, films.get(position));
            }
        });
        return recyclerView;
    }
}
```

XML Фрагмента списка

```
<FrameLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
   
        <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/filmsRecycler"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
</FrameLayout>
```

Код фрагмента самого фильма

```
public class FilmDetailFragment extends Fragment {

    private static final String ARG_PARAM1 = "film";
    private Film mParam1;

    public FilmDetailFragment() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }

    public static FilmDetailFragment newInstance(Film film) {
        FilmDetailFragment fragment = new FilmDetailFragment();
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putParcelable(ARG_PARAM1, film);
        fragment.setArguments(args);
        return fragment;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        if (getArguments() != null) {
            mParam1 = getArguments().getParcelable(ARG_PARAM1);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_detail_films, container, false);
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);

        ImageView imageView = getActivity().findViewById(R.id.imageView) ;

        Glide.with(getContext())
            .load(mParam1.getImageUrl())
            .error(Glide.with(imageView)
            .load(R.drawable.nothing))
            .into(imageView);
    }
}
```

XML фрагмента самого фильма

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".fragments.FilmDetailFragment">
```

```
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
     />
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: Ну во-первых вы не приложили ссылки на ваш репозиторий. Во-вторых никто не полезет по этой ссылке даже если она будет. Никто не будет делать вам код ревью еще и вопрос скорее всего закроют. Приложите проблемную часть кода на сайт. Было бы не плохо видеть ваш XML и код Activity

Comment: @SergeiBuvaka, прошу прощения, что не прикрепил ссылку на гит. 
А что касается кода, то боюсь это будет слишком много кода

Comment: Ну значит нужно убрать все лишнее. Если вы хотите чтоб человек потратил на вас свое время и помог вам, вы должны как минимум потрудится над тем, чтоб сохранить его время. Никому не хочется лезть в чужой репозиторий и пытаться там что-то найти. Так что уберите все лишнее, что по вашему мнение не относится к проблеме и покажите код здесь. Я вам даже дал подсказку что нужно показать. В противном случае шансы получить ответ стремятся к нулю

Comment: @SergeiBuvaka, ваше замечание уместно. Приложил код, если что то еще понадобиться приложу еще.

Comment: Фрагменты -- это очень легкий путь разложить себе граблей даже для опытного разработчика. Чтобы избавить нас от всего этого, придумали Navigation Framework. Может вам стоит потратить время на его изучение? https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation

Comment: @EugeneKrivenja, в том и дело, что я только осваиваю данную технологию и начинаю как раз таки с граблей. По этому и написал сюда в поисках совета как можно решить данную задачу.  Обязательно ознакомлюсь с Navigation Framework.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В итоге убрал fragment transaction. И сделал все на navigation через NavHostFragment и toolbar легко добавил. А кнопку вверх в toolbar он сам перехватывает.
Ну и вот хорошие статейки для размышления и ознакомления:

https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/navigation-ui

https://developersbreach.com/working-with-navigation-android-architecture-components/

А вообще конечно по NavigationUi android очень много полезных статей.